# How to solve that snowflake force the very small result of integer division to zero

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, divide-by-zero

I'm writing a snowflake query that calculate 1/2940744 and get the result equals to 0
How to solve to get the actual calculation result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs:

> [Division](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-arithmetic.html#division)
>
> When performing division:
>
> - The leading digits for the output is the sum of the leading digits of the numerator and the scale of the denominator.
> - **Snowflake minimizes potential overflow in the output (due to chained division) and loss of scale by adding 6 digits to the scale of the numerator, up to a maximum threshold of 12 digits, unless the scale of the numerator is larger than 12, in which case the numerator scale is used as the output scale.**
>
> In other words, assuming a division operation with numerator `L1.S1` and denominator `L2.S2`, the maximum number of digits in the output are calculated as follows:
>
> Scale   `S = max(S1, min(S1 + 6, 12))`
>
> **If the result of the division operation exceeds the output scale, Snowflake rounds the output (rather than truncating the output).**

Returning to example:

```
SELECT 1/2940744;
-- 0

DESC RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
```

[image]

The value `0.00000034005` was rounded to 0. In order to change the behaviour one of the arguments could be explicitly casted:

```
 SELECT 1::NUMBER(38,12)/2940744;
 -- 0.00000034005

 DESC RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
 -- 1::NUMBER(38,12)/2940744    NUMBER(38,12)
```

Comment: Awesome answer ...had no idea it just added 6dp . Why does it ignore zero's in this example : select 1.1/2940744,1.0/2940744;

Comment: @AdrianWhite The literals  1/1.0/1.00 have  the same inferred data type `NUMBER(1,0)`. If only zeros are involved they are ignored, `SELECT 1, 1.0, 1.00, 1.001;   
DESCRIBE RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
-- NUMBER(1,0)  NUMBER(1,0) NUMBER(1,0)  NUMBER(4,3)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer above, I check this answer late and solve the question myself by converting the result to `::double` -> 1/5000000::double